# Print in custom area from browesers

Tags: css, printing

I need print in a A4 paper and increase margins top and bottom in each page.
For example [image]
How do I do this in css?

Comment: You need crop your content or change content height?

Comment: Not, only reduce the print area...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<link>` tag as usual, and set `media="print"` which will apply styles for print, you can also go for `@print` media query and customize the layout which best suits the print.

```
@media print { 
    div {
        color: #f00;
    }

    /* Write custom styles here */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XHQYf/) (Checkout the print preview, text will turn red)

Comment: @LuizCarvalho you rewrite the styles for your elements inside that block, those styles will be applied when you print

Comment: @mr-alien any example?

Comment: You example make red color in div for a print, I need a example of reduce print area...

Comment: @LuizCarvalho don't reduce the print area, hide the elements which you don't want on print sheet using `display: none;`, and you resize the rest

Comment: @LuizCarvalho: Like Mr. Alien said: Do not display unnecessary elements in the print version. Here i've a nice article about Optimizing the print version of a website http://davidwalsh.name/optimizing-structure-print-css

Answer (score 0):

This resolve my problem.

```
@page {
    margin-top: 5cm !important;
    margin-bottom: 5cm !important;
}
```